# Help me learn how to use Services and Threads correctly

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, service

I'm asking for help so my life, and more importantly my user's lives will not be ruined by me not knowing how to use Services and Threads correctly.

I'm not asking for a long explanation, but more of a confirmation. It's fine if I'm dead wrong. I'm here to learn.

If I understand correctly:
1. a service runs in the background (no UI).
2. a service theoretically will run forever until it kills itself (I'm taking a big guess here)
3. a service will continue to run even when the main Activity is not visible (how about even destroyed?)

So here's my coding question.

I've got my service setup and a thread. Everything works great, but it only works once. I need it to loop and keep checking back. Once it's done run() how do I go about telling it to run() again?

```
public class NotifyService extends Service{

    private long mDoTask;

    NoteThread notethread;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mDoTask = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notethread = new NoteThread();
        notethread.start(); 
    }


    public class NoteThread extends Thread {
        NotificationManager nManager;
        Notification myNote;

        @Override
        public synchronized void start() {
            super.start();
//init some stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                    //If it's been x time since the last task, do it again
            //For testing set to every 15 seconds...
            if(mDoTask + 15000 < System.currentTimeMillis()){

//Take care of business
        mDoTask = System.currentTimeMillis();                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through this article for a good understanding of threads in Android. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Android docs:

> A Service is an application component
>   representing either an application's
>   desire to perform a longer-running
>   operation while not interacting with
>   the user or to supply functionality
>   for other applications to use. Each
>   service class must have a
>   corresponding  declaration in
>   its package's AndroidManifest.xml.
>   Services can be started with
>   Context.startService() and
>   Context.bindService().
>
> Note that services, like other
>   application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This
>   means that, if your service is going
>   to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3
>   playback) or blocking (such as
>   networking) operations, it should
>   spawn its own thread in which to do
>   that work. More information on this
>   can be found in Processes and Threads.
>   The IntentService class is available
>   as a standard implementation of
>   Service that has its own thread where
>   it schedules its work to be done.
>
> You can find a detailed discussion
>   about how to create services in the
>   Services document.

In other words, a service does NOT run in the background unless you put it in a thread.  If you put a service that never ends in your application without manually threading the service, then it *WILL* block.

Android provides an API to do background tasks for you without having to poke around with Java threads; it's called [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and it's one of the few GOOD design decisions that the Android team has ever made.

**EDIT** I forgot to address your question about multithreading.  You don't want to make a thread execute its `run()` method more than once.  Either instantiate a new thread or put a `while` loop around the contents of the `run` logic that you would like to have repeated.

Answer (score 0):

To understand threads better, read "Java Concurrency In Practice" by Brian Goetz.

To understand services better, I think you should write them to be single threaded and let the Java EE container you deploy them to handle threading issues.  A pooled servlet is a better solution than having your code shoulder the burden of managing threads for users.

Comment: not the correct context...  He's talking about an [Android Service Component](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), not J2EE development.